# How can i restart MSDTC service on remote server from client machine

Tags: c#, .net

I have requirement to restart MSDTC service on a remote server throw code  of my application .
Could you please help me through a code example.

Thanks and Regards
ShaBeg

Comment: delete hi and thanks. Should "Hi", "Thanks" and taglines and salutations be removed from posts? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController sc = 
    new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("Distributed Transaction Coordinator", "MachineName");
sc.Stop();
sc.Start();
```

The account under which the code is running will need to have admin rights on the remote box though. If not, you can do impersonation before running the code to impersonate a user with admin rights on the remote box.

MSDN info on the ServiceController class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SC` or `Netsvc` tools as described in [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/166819) technet article.

```
sc \\machine stop "Distributed Transaction Coordinator"
sc \\machine start "Distributed Transaction Coordinator"
```